# C# timestamp zero value can't read in my reader

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm having problem in getting the updated timestamp value which is returning `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. My reader cannot read the data  it gives an error saying `Invalid DateTime`.

I want to get only the time under TimeIn and TimeOut fields.

This is my code:

```
try
{
    SQLConn.sqL = "SELECT * FROM tblinformation WHERE " + search + " LIKE '" + strSearch + "%'";
    SQLConn.ConnDB();
    SQLConn.cmd = new MySqlCommand(SQLConn.sqL, SQLConn.conn);
    SQLConn.dr = SQLConn.cmd.ExecuteReader();

    ListViewItem x = null;
    listView2.Items.Clear();


    while (SQLConn.dr.Read() == true)
    {
        x = new ListViewItem(SQLConn.dr["AttendanceNo"].ToString());
        x.SubItems.Add(SQLConn.dr["RFIDNo"].ToString());
        x.SubItems.Add(SQLConn.dr["IDNumber"].ToString());
        x.SubItems.Add(SQLConn.dr["FullName"].ToString());
        x.SubItems.Add(SQLConn.dr["Designation"].ToString());
        x.SubItems.Add(DateTime.Parse(SQLConn.dr["TimeIn"].ToString()).ToShortTimeString());
        x.SubItems.Add(DateTime.Parse(SQLConn.dr["TimeOut"].ToString()).ToShortTimeString());
        x.SubItems.Add(SQLConn.dr["VPlateNo"].ToString());

        listView2.Items.Add(x);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Interaction.MsgBox(ex.ToString());
}
finally
{
    SQLConn.cmd.Dispose();
    SQLConn.conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: What data type is the SQL field?

Comment: I use TIMESTAMP

Comment: Gah, the SQL injection hole, it burns us!

Comment: Can i convert it to string and get the zero value from it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL Server allows an "invalid" `DATETIME` value `0000-00-00 00:00:00` to be stored (as long as the [`NO_ZERO_DATE` server mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) isn't set).

Since this isn't a valid .NET `DateTime` value, you need to add `AllowZeroDateTime=true` to your connection string, which will cause Connector/NET to return all `DATETIME` columns as the special `MySqlDateTime` type.

Alternatively, if you still want to use .NET's `DateTime` struct instead of `MySqlDateTime`, you can specify `ConvertZeroDateTime=true` in your connection string, which will convert `0000-00-00 00:00:00` to `DateTime.MinValue` when retrieving it from the database.

However, you should carefully check all your database insertion code to make sure you're not inserting invalid date/time values that MySQL Server is silently converting to `0000-00-00`. You should also use `STRICT` mode if at all possible, to avoid silent data loss.

Comment: Please do also follow @JoelCoehoorn's advice (in his answer) for improving your SQL query parameterisation and reading values.

Answer (score 3):

The MySql provider for ADO.Net retrieves MySql Timestamp columns as .Net DateTime objects. You do not want to call `SQLConn.dr["TimeIn"].ToString()`, *especially* when you're just gonna try to `Parse()` it again. The object in the reader field is *already* a DateTime value, so you can just do this:

```
x.SubItems.Add( ((DateTime)SQLConn.dr["TimeIn"]).ToShortTimeString() );
```

That will perform *way* better and be much less prone to errors. I'm not 100% certain it will fix the issue in the question, but it will certainly make debugging easier, especially if you separate it to two lines like this:

```
DateTime temp = (DateTime)SQLConn.dr["TimeIn"];
x.SubItems.Add( temp.ToShortTimeString() );
```

Now you can put a break point on the first line and check the actual value in the debugger.

---

While I'm here, I can't say strongly enough how **BAD** this is:

```
SQLConn.sqL = "SELECT * FROM tblinformation WHERE " + search + " LIKE '" + strSearch + "%'";
```

*This is the kind of code where you find out one morning you were hacked six months ago.*
**Don't do it.**

You need query parameters, like this:

```
SQLConn.cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblinformation WHERE column LIKE @search + '%';", SQLConn.conn);
SQLConn.Parameters.Add("@search", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = strSearch;
```

Even internal-only apps need to work this way. As a bonus, it also tends to perform faster, and can help with many DateTime and numeric formatting issues, since you work with native .Net types for the parameter values.

Comment: the same problem with this error unable to convert MySql date/time value to System.DateTime

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me in my code.. much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks... and it looks like  Bradley's answer has sniffed out the actual issue here. You should accept that one.

Comment: But i've got the same error, don't mind the toshorttimestring() what i want is to get the value even the returning default value is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 from updated timestamp

Comment: Yes, and Bradley Grainger's answer explains why... Your MySql database has an older configuration that violates the SQL standard here, and so allows invalid data the ADO.Net provider does not know how to convert correctly by default. You need to modify the connection string to tell it what to do, as explained in that answer.

Comment: exactly sir Joel Coehoorn.. thank you for your time and effort trying to fixed this..